# what am i doing wrong error: invalid operands to binary * (have 'float *' and 'int')|

Tags: c

I keep getting the same error message not sure how to correct it

```
  /*This program will prospective borrowers calculate monthly payment on a loan.
    The program also prints the amortization table to show the balance of the loan after each monthly payment.
    By: Kenneth Moore
    Date: 3/13/2016
    */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>>

const float monthInYear = 12; //This is a constant for the number of months in a year
const float percentTotal = 100; //This is a constant for calculating percentages

void getData (float* prPtr, float* nyPtr, float* iyPtr);

//this function will calculate the data for monthly payments based off APR and return the data to be printed on a table
float calculateMonthlyPayment (float* nmPtr, float* imPtr, float* pPtr, float* qPtr, float* mpPtr, float* nyPtr, float* iyPtr, float* prPtr); 
//This function will print the data
void printInformation (); 
//This function will display information in a table format
void printAmortizationTable (); 

int main()
{
    float nm;       //scheduled number of months for the loan
    float ny;       //scheduled number of years to amortize the loan
    float iy;       //interest rate per year as a percentage
    float im;       //interest rate/month decimal
    float pr;       //principal the amount of the loan
    float p;        //the value of (1+IM)
    float q;        //the value of P/(P-1)
    float mp;       //Monthly payment

    printf("Welcome the following program will help you decide how much loan you can afford.");
    printf("You will be prompted to enter the principle amount of the loan, the interest");
    printf("rate, and the length of the loan in years.  It will then show you on a table");
    printf("how much your monthly payment will be and how much of the loan remains after");
    printf("each payment.");

    getData (&pr, &ny, &iy);
    calculateMonthlyPayment(&nm, &im, &p, &q, &mp, &ny, &iy, &pr);
    return 0;
}

/*This function is a data collecting function the will collect user imputed data about the loan and calculate the interest and
payments to be printed in later functions*/ 
//Statement   
void getData (float* prPtr, float* nyPtr, float* iyPtr)
{
    printf("\nEnter the amount of money you wish to borrow.");
    scanf("%f", prPtr);
    printf("Enter the length in years for the loan.");
    scanf("%f", nyPtr);
    printf("Enter your expected interest rate.");
    scanf("%f", iyPtr);
    return;
}

//This function will now process the data to return the payment amount to be used in the table
float calculateMonthlyPayment (float* nmPtr, float* imPtr, float* pPtr, float* qPtr, float* mpPtr, float* nyPtr, float* iyPtr, float* prPtr)
{
    nmPtr =(nyPtr*12); //how many months the loan will be in effect
    imPtr =(iyPtr/monthInYear)/percentTotal; //how much interest is paid per month
    //this is my error location how can i reslove it

    pPtr = pow(1+imPtr,nmPtr);
    qPtr = pPtr/(pPtr-1);
    mpPtr = (prPtr*imPtr*qPtr);
}
```

Comment: I would say that this is c++ and not c#. Maybe you can change the tag so the right people see your question :-)

Comment: @pkeuter it's C. Not C++.

Comment: @BartFriederichs Ah yeah you're right. Well it definitely wasn't c#

Comment: @pkeuter That we definitely agree on ;-).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are multiplier a pointer with a constant. I reckon you want the value of where the pointer is pointing at. Use pointer-dereference operator `*` for that (same goes for `nmPtr`, and by the way the other pointers in that function):

```
*nmPtr =(*nyPtr*12);
```

Comment: i used pointer-dereference  and the errors went away but now i cannot get the program to calculate properly any idea